# how to bi-transmitted between two Android NFC phones?

Tags: android, nfc, bidirectional, ndef

How can I implement NDEF can be bi-transmitted between two Android phones? I mean one phone send, the other phone receive and response back immediately and interactively. How to achieve that in two Android phones?

I need NFC phone like a chat mode. Data can be communicated each other.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, this is not supported in Android right now. Many people want and need this. I suggest you add your vote for this feature on http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=28014